# Objective-C: Receive "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" signal

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to get iPhone screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710903/exc-bad-access-when-trying-to-get-iphone-screen-dimensions)

I have the following code snippet in objective-c that automatically sets some variables to a number of presets. However, on the marked line I get a "Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" exception.

What confuses me is that the line above is identical, just with a different value. If line 1 does not throw an exception, why should line 2? What can I do about this?

Thanks in advance!

Sterren

```
- (IBAction)presetPressed:(id)sender {
    if(self.userEnteringNumber) [self enterPressed];

    double xVal;
    double aVal;
    double bVal;
    NSString *preset = [sender currentTitle];
    if ([preset isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        xVal = 1;
        aVal = 2;
        bVal = 3;
    } else if ([preset isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        xVal = 1.5;
        aVal = 2.9;
        bVal = 3.0;
    } else if ([preset isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        xVal = -1;
        aVal = -2;
        bVal = -3;
    }
    [self.variables setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:xVal] forKey:@"x"];
    [self.variables setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:aVal] forKey:@"a"];
    [self.variables setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:bVal] forKey:@"b"];

    self.xVar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"= %@", xVal];
    self.aVar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"= %@", aVal]; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
    self.bVar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"= %@", bVal];

    [self calculateResult];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. Part of the question is related to why this works for the first statement but not the second. Also, all 3 statements happen to work when preset == "1". If %@ is only supposed to work for objects and not primitives, why does it sometimes work and sometimes not?

Comment: Thank you respondents! Your help is greatly appreciated. Both your solutions, T Reddy and Till, are excellent. However, armed with the information that %@ is for objects, I decided for the following solution;

    self.xVar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"= %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:xVal]];

This ensures that the text in xVar is formatted nicely without unnecessary trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xVal`, `aVal`, `bVal` are all primitive doubles, but yet your string format is looking for an object via `%@`.

try replacing `%@` with `%f` (or `%g` if you prefer scientific notation):

```
    self.xVar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"= %f", xVal];
    self.aVar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"= %f", aVal];
    self.bVar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"= %f", bVal];
```

Comment: Thank you T_Reddy. You answered without prejudice. I apologise that I am new to objective-c for the rest of you and that I sometimes do not ask the right questions.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your formatting strings `@"= %@"` with `@"= %g"`.

Your formatting string was assuming that the given parameter value would be an object instance  (`%@`) but you supplied a scalar double value which is not an object instance but of a primitive type.